# Why has my hardwood floor buckled 10 years after installation?

Tags: hardwood-floor

So I installed hardwood flooring in my dining room about 10 years ago and in the last week, it buckled on one side of the room (about 4 inches high!). When I pulled the flooring up to cut down the last row, there was no moisture in the subfloor. I had left room for expansion/contraction when I installed it but again, this was 10 years ago and I haven’t had ANY problems with buckling until last week. The only thing I can think of is that I got a new AC unit last year, but if anything I would think that would decreases the humidity in my home.

Comment: Under the floor is what? Concrete? Crawl space? Another air conditioned level of the home? An unfinished basement?

Comment: If the interior if the home is now cooler with new ac unit and the underside of the dining floor is warm condensation will occur. A moisture reading should betaken on the bottom of subfloor

Comment: It’s moisture. We found a leaky pipe after a few years in one job. I like Kris’ suggestion, take moisture readings around the house. Something has changed.

Comment: Sad to say, but underground streams do change course once in a while.